# Do we mention a girlfriend in UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have another question regarding the UK visa application process.

We are hoping so he can come on holiday for 3 weeks in January.
Do we give the information that I am his girlfriend? Of course, I don't want to hide it, but when researching this I have seen a lot of people say that you shouldn't give information you aren't asked for. We're putting me down as one of the friends he knows in the country so I wouldn't be surprised if the ECO found out I was his girlfriend anyway, so I don't want it to look like we were lying by omission. I know having a girlfriend in the country weakens the application, but I also don't want to ruin chances of future visas.

Should we put 'I am visiting the country as a tourist for a holiday from university and to visit my girlfriend' or do we not mention the girlfriend part unless explicitly asked?

Comment: Hi, please see the question I've linked. The consensus is that girl/boyfriends should not be described just as "friends". In normal English, you wouldn't describe your partner as just a friend, unless you were trying to hide something! Having a partner in the country can in some sense "weaken" the application, but as you rightly state, if the ECO or border officer believes you've lied by omission, it will seriously imperil any future visits to the UK.

Comment: @MJeffryes thank you for the link and the useful info! If it shouldn't be described as friend, should he not list me in the friend section where you give contact details? And in the first question, should he tick he's visiting for tourism or visiting friends? thank you!!

Comment: I believe that there is somewhere in the form to explain your relationship to the people you’ve listed as friends. Yes, the purpose of trip should be “visiting friends”. It doesn’t matter exactly where he says he’s visiting his girlfriend, as long as he does it somewhere!